# Conditional group on column attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with these columns: `pk`, `gender`, `attribute` and want to select top 10 attributes per gender. Currently I use two queries to accomplish that:

```
SELECT attribute, count(attribute)
FROM tab
WHERE gender=1
GROUP BY attribute
ORDER BY count(attribute) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and another query for `WHERE gender=0`.

Can I make this to one query, and output both top 10 attributes per gender

`male_attribute, count, female_attribute, count`

Comment: Is this postgresql ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: yes pg 9.5

Comment: use a union clause

Comment: ok union operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a Pivot Table solution would fit better your scenario. The response will be like:

```
 attribute     male     female
     A          10        12
     B           9         8 
     C           7         8
     D           6         5
     E           3         4
```

To get such result the SQL for PostgreSQL would be:

```
select attribute,
       sum(gender0) gender0,
       sum(gender1) gender1
  from (select attribute,
               case when gender=0 then 1 else 0 end as gender0,
               case when gender=1 then 1 else 0 end as gender1
          from tab) as tab
 group by attribute
 order by (case when sum(gender0)>sum(gender1) 
                then sum(gender0) 
                else sum(gender1) end) desc
 limit 10
```

Since you didn't specify which is male and female I left it as `gender0` and `gender1`

Explaining the lines that I think it would look strange:

```
 order by (case when sum(gender0)>sum(gender1) 
                then sum(gender0) 
                else sum(gender1) end) desc
```

This line will check which value is bigger the `sum` from `gender0` or the `sum` from `gender1` and will order by it `desc`. That way you will have the bigger value of the two first.

If you need any more explanation let me know.

See it working here (the values are different on working sample): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1432/1

Comment: Thanks, I actually did try to pivot with `crosstab` (for the first time), and couldn't make it work

Answer (score 2):

You can.  The easiest way is to use variables:

```
SELECT gender, attribute, cnt
FROM (SELECT ag.*,
             (@rn := if(@g = gender, @rn + 1,
                        if(@g := gender, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT gender, attribute, count(attribute) as cnt
            FROM tab
            GROUP BY gender, attribute
            ORDER BY gender, cnt DESC
           ) ag CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @g := -1) params
     ) ag
WHERE seqnum <= 10;
```

With two values for gender, separate queries is probably simpler.  However, if you have more values, then this approach has its merits.

EDIT:

The solution in Postgres is much simpler:

```
select gender, attribute, cnt
from (select gender, attribute, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from tab t
      group by gender, attribute
     ) ga
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this looks too complicated for me. I expected simpler solution, assuming I'm new to sql...

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . The edited version does (and it is much simpler).  I must've misread the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Likely Less efficient than other answers... but easier to read...

[Working SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a11/1/0)

The use of a UNION statement can combine two queries with the same number of columns and data types.

For the limits and order by to be applied to their respective sets, I believe we simply wrap the selects in ()'s...   This is needed due to the last ORder by and limit may be applied to the whole set otherwise.

```
(SELECT attribute, count(attribute), 1 as gender 
FROM tab
WHERE gender=1
GROUP BY attribute
ORDER BY count(attribute) DESC
LIMIT 10)

UNION ALL

(SELECT attribute, count(attribute), 0 as gender
FROM tab
WHERE gender=0
GROUP BY attribute
ORDER BY count(attribute) DESC
LIMIT 10)
```